# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matches')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I am trying to filter through an Array of Objects (Albums in my case), but I am getting this Error and everything I tried did not work.

**My Searchbar :**

```
<input type="search" placeholder={" "} onChange={e => onChangeHandler(e.target.value)} value={text}/>
```

**My onChangeHandler**

```
const onChangeHandler =(text) => {
        let matches = []
        if (text.length > 0){
            matches = albums.filter(album => {
                const regex = new RegExp(`${text}`, "gi")
                return (album.artist.matches(regex));
            });
        }
        console.log('matches', matches)
        setSuggestions(matches)
        setText(text)
    }
```

When I try, it works and I get the matches in the console, but only if I type everything correctly and case sensitive. That is not the goal tho.

```
return (album.artist === text);
```

Comment: what does your albums look like?

Comment: This is not related to a regex right now, `album.artist` seems to be `undefined`.

Comment: Can you please show us what your albums array looks like ? if it returned "cannot read properties matches of undefined "it means that album.artist is undefined

Comment: As everyone said, most likely you are missing "artist" of an "album". You can go over that by using optional chaining like ```return (album?.artist?.matches?.(regex));```  so your filter leaves out any albums without artist info.

Comment: @OrionCygnus this one worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use includes method of strings for this. So for your example something like this:

```
matches = albums.filter(album => album.artist.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()));
```

If you want the search to be case sensitive, you should remove toLowerCase methods.

Answer (score -1):

There are probably 2 issues in your code. First it doesn't seem to find the `album.artist` so make sure your object looks correct.

Secondly `matches()` is not a function on a String and you probably meant `match()`

```js
let albums = [{
  artist: "Me"
}, {
  artist: "You"
}]

const onChangeHandler = (text) => {
  let matches = []
  if (text.length > 0) {
    matches = albums.filter(album => {
      const regex = new RegExp(`${text}`, "gi")
      return (album.artist.match(regex)); // Here matches => match
    });
  }
  console.log('matches', matches)
  //setSuggestions(matches)
  //setText(text)
}
onChangeHandler("mE")
onChangeHandler("me")
onChangeHandler("yo")
```

Comment: Yeah it was match before. I changed it to matches just to try something out. Still got the error with only match. But the comment above from Orion Cygnus worked.

Comment: For further questions try to include something like your albums array, since the undefined tells us there is something wrong with the thing you called the function on, thus everybody was asking for your albums xD